# PHP check if variable from $_GET is integer

Tags: php

The solution below is what I have cooked up to check that a variable from $_GET is an integer. It seems a bit convoluted and I am sure that there must be a simpler solution. The error array is used to show the user messages.

```
    // Create array to hold errors
    $errors = array();

    // Get ID from URL
    $user_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';

    // Check for empty ID
    if (empty($user_id)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Empty user ID');
    } else {
        // Check if ID is numeric
        if (!is_numeric($user_id)) {
            array_push($errors, 'Invalid user ID');
        } else {
            // Get numerical value of string (int or float)
            $num_user_id = $user_id + 0;
            // Check that number is an int
            if (!is_integer($num_user_id))
                array_push($errors, 'Invalid user ID');
        }
    }
```

Comment: check out http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-input.php

Comment: Did you tried ``(int)$_GET['id']``

Comment: `if(empty($_GET['id']) || !is_integer((int)$_GET['id']) { $errors[]='Invalid user ID';}`

Comment: you can try `filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Empty user id';
} else if (!ctype_digit($_GET['id'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Invalid id';
} else {
    $num_user_id = (int)$_GET['id'];
}
```

That covers all possibilities: not set and not numeric.

That is if you need to differentiate your error messages between *not set* and *not numeric*. Otherwise [`filter_input`](http://php.net/filter_input) is something you should look at.

---

Arguably you should probably be more relaxed about the specific invalidity; an invalid id is an invalid id and it hardly matters why it's invalid. There are more reasons why an id could be invalid than why it is valid. Caring about all of these reasons individually is not necessarily worth the effort.

I'm assuming that you're fetching a user record from a database with this id; your error control should probably more follow this logic:

- if `$_GET['id']` is not set at all:

  - error 400, bad request
- else fetch database record with given id, not caring at all what the id looks like (but be aware of what invalid values might cast to and whether you might need to care about that after all)

  - if no record found:

    - error 404, not found
  - else:

    - display page

To that extend, `filter_input` is perfect:

```
if (!$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
    exit;
}

if (!$user = get_user_record($id)) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
}

echo $user;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will take your suggestions on board and talk to the others working on the same project as me.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your incoming GET with `(int)`. Then when this number is `greater than 0`, it was already a valid number.

```
<?php
$user_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0;

if(0 < $user_id) {
    // Do your foo and bars
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this simple function:

```
<?php
    function isInteger($input){
        return(ctype_digit(strval($input)));
    }
    $user_id  = isInteger($_GET['id']);

    if($user_id) {
        // its numeric
    } else {
        // it is not numeric
    }
?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Taking this concept in action for you:

```
<?php
// Create array to hold errors
    $errors = array();

    // Get ID from URL
    $user_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';

    // Check for empty ID
    if (empty($user_id)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Empty user ID');
    } else {
        if(!ctype_digit(strval($user_id))) {
            array_push($errors, 'Invalid user ID');
        } else {
            // Get numerical value of string (int or float)
            $num_user_id = $user_id + 0;
            // Check that number is an int
            if (!ctype_digit(strval($num_user_id)))
                array_push($errors, 'Invalid user ID');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This will produce notices since you cannot be sure that `$_GET['id']` *is set*.

Comment: @deceze Yeah but it was just a hint for him, updated the answer. BTW thank you for deducting my two points ;)